# Should I write and answer an interesting question that I couldn't found answered in the forum?

Tags: discussion, self-answer

I had a question and couldn't find it properly answered in the forum, just little things little related that can help a little bit (I am not saying that it does not exist, just saying that I couldn't find it). But just before asking the question, I found a way to do it. So now I have an answer to that, and the question seems to be interesting to me. Should I post it and answer my own question?

Comment: Related: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26564/formulating-the-problem-helps-solving-it-self-answer-or-delete-question

Comment: @kingW3 I didn't even formulated it....

Comment: Without knowing more about your Question, I can only advise that if you would post it, you do give a careful formulation of the problem that you (originally) wanted help with.  It's great you were able to find a solution that meets your own needs, and likely there will be others in the future with the same problem.  However the Question may have been properly answer on Math.SE before, and it may be closed as a duplicate if that turns out to be the case.

Comment: Maybe you can look at older discussions tagged ([meta-tag:self-answer]). For example: [Recently rolled out SE Encyclopedia feature](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4286), [Views on asking and answering questions solely to make results available on stack exchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4337) or [Can I post a question and an answer just because I think it helps others?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15017)

Comment: See also https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1190/is-math-puzzle-on-topic-or-off-topic